# Merge Sort Array of Integers

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with this pratice question: 33 31 11 47 2 20 24 12 2 43. I am trying to figure out what the contents of the two output lists would be after the first pass of the Merge Sort.

The answer is supposedly: 
List 1: 33 11 47 12
List 2: 31 2 20 24 2 43

Not making any sense to me sense I was under the impression that the first pass was where it divided it into two lists at the middle....

Comment: This division into two lists does look a little odd.

Comment: Where are you getting the supposed answer from? Is this in a textbook?

Comment: its from an online program http://cs2.uco.edu/~mcdaniel/prog2/run-executable.php?progname=merge

Comment: It appears that this is some sort of heuristic division - rather than just alternating between output lists or taking first half / second half, it is switching lists whenever the next element is less than the current one. So 33 goes on first list, 31 goes on second, 11 back to first list, but then 47 > 11, so we stay on the same list until we get to the 2... and so on. Can't say I've seen that particular heuristic before, so I'm not sure what the benefits are... I guess it provides a small amount of pre-sorting of short sequences...

Answer (score 0):

33 31 11 47 2 20 24 12 
At first the list divides into individual elements such that when a single ton list is formed each element is compared with the one next to it. So after first pass we have

31 33    11 47    2 20    12 24
After that

11 31 33 47        2 12 20 24
and then

2 11 12 20 24 3133 37

Comment: i guess i missed the last two elements.But you follow the same proceedure as above and you will get to know how the passes dryrun mate!!..cheers!!